# How to prevent a cronjob foreach loop from sending an email to EVERY result row?

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron

I have a cron job that looks at a table and sends emails accordingly.

The table is very simple with just:

- cronid (auto-increment primary key id)
- groupid (id of the group the user is in)
- sent (0 by default, will be updated to 1 after cron-job runs)

The script (below) finds all rows with `sent` = 0 and loops through to send emails.

```
//find all instances of a hunch being submitted that haven't yet had notification emails sent, and loop thru and send emails
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cronid, groupid FROM cron_email_notify WHERE sent = 0 ");
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $cronid=$row['cronid']; 
    $groupid=$row['groupid'];

    //phpmailer stuff to actually send emails goes here, not relevantto this question

    //update cron_email_notify table's sent field to 1, so we know not to send again
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE cron_email_notify SET sent = 1 WHERE groupid = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$groupid]);
}
```

I had 4 entries for the same group number with `sent`=0, so I assumed this code above would send the first email, then the last query would update all other rows with that group number to have `sent` = 1, and therefore it wouldn't send the other 3.  But I tested and 4 separate emails were sent.

Took me a minute to realize (I know, pretty dumb) that the original query and foreach loop is finding all 4 rows right away and then we're looping thru those 4, regardless of any changes made during the loop.  So even tho I updated `sent` to be 1 for the other 3 rows after the first email was sent, it was still going to finish looping through the original query results (i.e. all 4 rows) and send 4 emails.

So my question now is, how could I set this up to search for all rows that have `sent` = 0 but only send ONE email per group number. I'm thinking maybe I use GROUP BY or UNIQUE in the original query? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Add a `GROUP BY` to the first query

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cronid, groupid FROM cron_email_notify WHERE sent = 0 GROUP BY groupid");
```

And then in the query inside your loop ad another condition to the `WHERE` statement to make sure you're not updating records that are allready okay.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE cron_email_notify SET sent = 1 WHERE groupid = ? AND sent = 0");
```

I'm not sure how often you run the cronjob and how long it takes but the way it is now you could be updating records that have been added later then when you're retrieving them.

Comment: Thank you, I'll add the GROUP BY.  In regards to your last thought, it's likely going to run every minute.  Are you saying this setup might update a new entry that came in JUST after I retrieved the original result set?

Comment: Yeah it is possible but wheter it matters or not is up to you :-)